# Proper way to compute time in openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I wrote a serial and parallel code for matrix multiplication and I compute the time in the serial code and got 4 seconds. However, in the parallel code, when I run it using for example 4 threads and compute the time and I get more than 20 and every time the number of threads is increased, the time is increased too. So I want to know what's wrong.
here is the openmp code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int r1,c1;
    int r2,c2;
    int i,j,k;
    int **mat1;
    int **mat2;
    int **result;

    srand(time(0));

    double time_spent = 0;

    printf("Enter dimensions of the first matrix: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);

    mat1 = (int **)malloc(r1 * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        mat1[i] = (int *)malloc(c1 * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
            mat1[i][j] = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;



    printf("Enter dimensions of the second matrix: \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);

    mat2 = (int **)malloc(r2 * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        mat2[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));


    for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            mat2[i][j] = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;



    result = (int **)malloc(r1 * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        result[i] = (int *)malloc(c2 * sizeof(int));

    #pragma omp parallel private(i, j, k) shared(mat1, mat2, result)
    {

        clock_t begin = clock();
        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(i = 0;i<r1;i++){

            for(j = 0;j<c2;j++){
                for(k=0;k<r2;k++){

                    result[i][j] +=  mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                }

            }

        }
        clock_t end = clock();
        time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    }
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", time_spent);
    printf("\n");
    /*for(i=0;i<r1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<c2;j++){
            printf("%d ",result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }*/
    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        free(mat1[i]);
    free(mat1);

    for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        free(mat2[i]);
    free(mat2);

    for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        free(result[i]);
    free(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Proper way to compute time in openmp"*

OpenMP has nothing to do with this, this is related to the indirect accounting of how many CPU-ticks (stored inside CPU-core low-level hardware registers) have been accumulated from (all) threads, which actually can run in multiple instances at the same time. Compare that to the [OpenMP native tool](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu160.html) :
**`double omp_get_wtime(void);`**

You may like to experiment with more [**run-time**](https://tio.run/##xVZtb6NGEP7uXzHyyScggGHBb5dLpTbKh6on5ZS0n1wrIrA42LwJ8PVUK/3p9c0AMWDjBJ966soy7OzOPDv7DDNjK0vb3u3eeaHtbxwOH9PM8SL16adeJYqCuCnAPb732JRlXsBJ0vPCDALLC0GgNytZ2jLYT1YCEr5/mS9E2PZ6gIOWEx0X9ctqznDOqrknw0qGdSWQpMDK9IM5q88Tnm787LLASBMrdASgwwmaCGIpdqLNo89z8UMac9S7Ao3WhkOIE7TjCtC/CTOegIN7wtSLwhQiF7InDq6XpORilnhfP8CfYZ/MkmZqWyEqQn/gDJy@DO/Ju/e2nq/jSHSEsekvYfRGfzozzGL1jEFXUL5eFdcsSWJg@X5kC4QiQer9zSOXliTxBd6NEgG83FN8fMSN@Ly4ALEdYO4tagBQAdhNAGgC5ES0gOx9zHetih0r3IH0w@r4GOUR5qsF3RJcAHpGXIowwFddAyWX6lCy2oW5lNtR6LxCXcUcI@bYi2fnccNOc8Ne4@bw6lgrPwRwmht2DjfsTW7YKW7YOdycN4oP@AdGdwGQ32HHG@wN/5/Ry39wG8RKtMmUIEoz5ZdPt9e/kfR4/I4RD9y34pQ7HwA0VdPM0XQCc0oz8BXosQBFM7qqsxkztaZ6J9WRysZjU5vBnPIbqtIDkW8NNFbmdFjAP/BHih8qpWFUYuqEzSBFa3fc8l@kumpOdUi7wJpjVTOnI91ownZRnRiqMTMYY60npuPKGFWdTE3H6mw6HU3bnV/nznuHzpuGOsZzHzjPmGrq5Dzh/jWMKBBquCS1IN4kXJnf39z9@vOnRXsQ6KOp9v1BoGMYfE8QmKo2GY1m@llBYKpMOw4ClM7G3YKAGappTOisTVgaJ2FRacS0o@s31IneEdZk6hhD7yjkC9hTrGPIjyaHsBgLOn60BFvkzndxYi0DC7APg9hKMFFxn4rdFyvjQumRCCn2WNwRqG7KeYaWy0RXpPftPg0PJeU/HNIQbEyc64cMHvkS276rYi7USmfdAczTWG2fuLPxuZBmVubZB/WnGusina/LWrWmdL5tlpNKo61sbVtqz8lCse29WpDKgndxVfUm6wXWirwYrmntuFd47rXPnn88GRwbnRYqai0veiIUjbAo5NuVkkERhnBNVeb@4fPN3cP9zXWhX5x632U1P4CBi@2UXLdfou73l@0W9ltSjbY3mHi1I9mbHjjQl5s81Tu3wyPkzoBUfl5vdw5uwrmwb4rFy6bsZAfCTtphLXZY906m0KnaGLJUl5Gl593uX9v1rWW6U9wICQniHabebw) options live [here,](https://tio.run/##xVZtb6NGEP7uXzHyyScggGHBb5dLpTbKh6on5ZS0n1wrIrA42LwJ8PVUK/3p9c0AMWDjBJ966soy7OzOPDv7DDNjK0vb3u3eeaHtbxwOH9PM8SL16adeJYqCuCnAPb732JRlXsBJ0vPCDALLC0GgNytZ2jLYT1YCEr5/mS9E2PZ6gIOWEx0X9ctqznDOqrknw0qGdSWQpMDK9IM5q88Tnm787LLASBMrdASgwwmaCGIpdqLNo89z8UMac9S7Ao3WhkOIE7TjCtC/CTOegIN7wtSLwhQiF7InDq6XpORilnhfP8CfYZ/MkmZqWyEqQn/gDJy@DO/Ju/e2nq/jSHSEsekvYfRGfzozzGL1jEFXUL5eFdcsSWJg@X5kC4QiQer9zSOXliTxBd6NEgG83FN8fMSN@Ly4ALEdYO4tagBQAdhNAGgC5ES0gOx9zHetih0r3IH0w@r4GOUR5qsF3RJcAHpGXIowwFddAyWX6lCy2oW5lNtR6LxCXcUcI@bYi2fnccNOc8Ne4@bw6lgrPwRwmht2DjfsTW7YKW7YOdycN4oP@AdGdwGQ32HHG@wN/5/Ry39wG8RKtMmUIEoz5ZdPt9e/kfR4/I4RD9y34pQ7HwA0VdPM0XQCc0oz8BXosQBFM7qqsxkztaZ6J9WRysZjU5vBnPIbqtIDkW8NNFbmdFjAP/BHih8qpWFUYuqEzSBFa3fc8l@kumpOdUi7wJpjVTOnI91ownZRnRiqMTMYY60npuPKGFWdTE3H6mw6HU3bnV/nznuHzpuGOsZzHzjPmGrq5Dzh/jWMKBBquCS1IN4kXJnf39z9@vOnRXsQ6KOp9v1BoGMYfE8QmKo2GY1m@llBYKpMOw4ClM7G3YKAGappTOisTVgaJ2FRacS0o@s31IneEdZk6hhD7yjkC9hTrGPIjyaHsBgLOn60BFvkzndxYi0DC7APg9hKMFFxn4rdFyvjQumRCCn2WNwRqG7KeYaWy0RXpPftPg0PJeU/HNIQbEyc64cMHvkS276rYi7USmfdAczTWG2fuLPxuZBmVubZB/WnGusina/LWrWmdL5tlpNKo61sbVtqz8lCse29WpDKgndxVfUm6wXWirwYrmntuFd47rXPnn88GRwbnRYqai0veiIUjbAo5NuVkkERhnBNVeb@4fPN3cP9zXWhX5x632U1P4CBi@2UXLdfou73l@0W9ltSjbY3mHi1I9mbHjjQl5s81Tu3wyPkzoBUfl5vdw5uwrmwb4rFy6bsZAfCTtphLXZY906m0KnaGLJUl5Gl593uX9v1rWW6U9wICQniHabebw) to see all the improvement impacts from better, more cache-efficient RAM-I/O and other OpenMP scheduling, thread-capacites, sharing-avoidance and other options of choice.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Omp-out-most-BLOCK
//                   Time elapsed:  0.004587 [ 123 x  123] -03
//                   Time elapsed:  0.029240 [ 123 x  123]
//                   Time elapsed:  5.266409 [1234 x 1234] -O3 [ i, j, k ] ~ User time:  2.729 s   Real time:  1.481 s
//                   Time elapsed: 46.048513 [1234 x 1234]
//                   Time elapsed: 73.393222 [1234 x 1234] -O3 [ j, k, i ]
//                   Time elapsed: 86.988589 [1234 x 1234] -O3 [ k, j, i ] ~ User time: 43.613 s   Real time: 22.411 s

// w/o Omp           
// a pure-[SERIAL]   Time elapsed:  0.001580 [ 123 x  123] -03
//                   Time elapsed:  0.010290 [ 123 x  123]
//                   Time elapsed:  4.075591 [1234 x 1234] -O3 [ i, j, k ] ~ User time:  4.209 s   Real time:  4.296 s
//                   Time elapsed: 23.437123 [1234 x 1234]     [ i, j, k ] ~ User time: 23.520 s   Real time: 23.716 s
//                   Time elapsed: 42.685109 [1234 x 1234]     [ k, j, i ] ~ User time: 42.757 s   Real time: 43.187 s
//
```